# How to select a default emulator for android while developing an app in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I have many android emulators created on my machine. The problem is, whenever I run my react native project using 'react-native run-android', a new emulator opens even if one is already open.
I would prefer to select a specific emulator that starts every time no emulator is running or if any other emulator is running. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using below command :

```
react-native run-android --emulator MyEmulatorName
```

You can get Emulator name by following commands:

```
adb devices // this should return like "emulator-5554"
adb -s emulator-5554 emu avd name //pass name returned in above command. You should be able to get your emulator name like "Phone_API_28" and you can pass that in first command.
```

Comment: Tried this. 
Returns the following - 
`error: unknown option '-- emulator'`
Do I need to give the path of the emulator folder somewhere?